# Why did Jacob keep working for Lavan 7 additional years and didn't resign and divorce Lea

Tags: tanach

After the rotten lie of Lavan to Jacob and replacing Lea with Rachel. Why did Jacob keep working for additional 7 years? Didn't he understand that he couldn't trust Lavan and he could lie him again about Rachel. Isn't it a gamble to trust un-trusted person. He should leave Lavan house at once and try to solve the problem. In addition, why didn't he divorce Lea, since she wasn't the woman he wants to get married to?

Comment: How long after marrying Leah do you believe he married Rachel?

Comment: According to one of the Mefarshim 7 days?

Comment: According to Bereishit 29:28 it was 7 days. So I'm not sure I understand your question: what's the worry about not trusting Lavan again, he already married Rachel before he worked the additional 7 years

Comment: This is only one explanation. The Pshat is literally 7 years. Moreover, even if you explain it as 7 days, why did he keep working 7 additional years for a deal that was defined as 7 years for Rachel. In addition, why did he stay in un-trusted person house even just for salary? And why didn't he divorce from Lea?

Comment: who says that he worked the full seven years before marrying Rachel? I don't think I've seen any commentator suggest that. Bereishit 29:30 is pretty clear that he married Rachel and then worked for seven years

Comment: Even according to your answer. There are several additional questions (see above). In addition, according to Pshat he worked additional 7 years: ויעבוד עימו, עוד שבע-שנים אחרות

Comment: He certainly worked seven more years, but only after he had married Rachel, so the main question in your post makes little sense. Your other questions are stronger, but are unlikely to be answered unless you [edit] them into the question, rather than leaving them as comments. Also, multiple questions in one post are discouraged, so make sure that they really are multiple facets of one overarching question, rather than separate questions which should be asked in separate posts

Comment: Thanks @JoelK! I wrote the questions as one question since they are interrelated. In addition, according to Pshat the question still exist. Please feel free to edit and change my question for the benefit of the readers.